# ¿Cómo evitar que aplicación se oculte al escribir o abrir otro programa?

Tags: java

Cómo puedo evitar que la aplicación se oculte al abrir otra aplicación o al intentar escribir en word, la aplicación se oculta, como hacer que está aplicación siempre esté al flote de cualquier aplicación es decir que siempre este visible sin importar que aplicación o programa abra o que actividad realice.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código java:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


/**
 *
 * @author inide
 */
public class texscroll extends JPanel {
    int  x =510 , y = 25;

    //x = El texto inicia desde la derecha.
    //y = El texto se mueve en la parte superior.

    @Override

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        //Font.PLAIN,15 = Tamaño de la fuente
        Font font = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD + Font.PLAIN,15);
        g2.setFont(font);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        String string ="Con un presupuesto superior a los 3 millones de"
                + " soles, entregado a la empresa constructora ARC, y "
                + "adjudicándose a la empresa supervisora chultong, se"
                + " reiniciarán los trabajos de construccion y culminación "
                + "de la infraestructura de la institución educativa gran"
                + " unidad escolar san carlos en la ciudad de puno.";
        g2.drawString(string ,x,y);
        //Velocidad en el que se mueve el texto, defaul(10) menor a ese valor el texto
        //se mueve a mayor velocidad.
        try{Thread.sleep(14);}
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        };
        x-=1;

            if(x==-10*string.length()){
              x= 510;  
            }
        repaint();

       // System.out.println(string.length()  );
    }
}
```

Parte 2

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
/**
 *
 * @author inide
 */
public class Textmovie {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       JFrame jf = new JFrame("FGHJK");
       jf.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
       jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       jf.add(new texscroll());
       jf.setSize(720,480);

       jf.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta agregando un `JFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);` a tu `Jframe` en el método main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       JFrame jf = new JFrame("FGHJK");
       jf.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
       jf.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
       jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       jf.add(new texscroll());
       jf.setSize(720,480);

       jf.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Comment: Gracias funciono perfectamente :)